# How to remove 'A_' from all header using Import-excel Powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

Please find below data I have, I need to remove A_ value in all header in my csv file , I am trying multiple ways but no luck.
[CSV Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As1g2.png)

Here is the code , but It's not worked for me:

```
$CSVpath="C:\test1.csv"
$gevalue = Get-Content $CSVpath
For($i=0 ; $i -le 4 ; $i++){
$a=((Get-Content $CSVpath)[0] -split(','))[$i]
$b= $a -replace 'A_' , '' 
$temp =$gevalue; 
$temp[0] = $temp[0].replace($temp[$i],$b);
Set-Content -Path $CSVpath -Value $temp;
}
```

Note: This data is only in CSV file and also, I also tried powershell using import-csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to remove all occurences of `A_` in the header line you can use the following snippet:

```
$CSVpath = "C:\test1.csv"
$Content = Get-Content $CSVpath
$Content[0] = $Content[0] -replace 'A_'
$Content | Set-Content -Path $CSVpath
```